# create word document(docx) without using third party dll in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, docx

I have mvc page. I have letter kind of page(cshtml) and will be populating data from modal. once i ll click okay button on this page. It should create a word document or pdf of the letter and i need to store this path in DB (I SHOULD NOT USE ANY THIRDPARTY DLL :( ) Can you guys please help me move on this?

Thanks,
Sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please specify what do you consider as third party? 
If you can't add libraries, then you would not have a choice, but create a PDF writing library yourself, and that is not a trivial task. 
For working with Word documents you can use Interop classes that are from Microsoft, but they are not build for that originally.
If you can use Interop, have a look on this [tutorial](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/creating-word-document-using-c/) and [this one](http://windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/2006/04/18/programming-word-from-net.html?page=1)

Comment: I can use microsoft refernces but not the other dll's

Answer (score 1):

If you don't consider Microsoft as a third party try:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx